# Remove 3D effect of the background of a button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I use the following code to make checkbox buttons: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nayizus/1/edit?html,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">INPUT</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't like the 3D effect of the background of the button:

[image]

I would prefer the SAME gray colour as the background. Does anyone know how to realise this?

PS: I would like to stick to using `<button>` rather than `<input>` and `<a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I have with Bootstrap is you constantly need to override their default styling and you have to be very specific about how you target the element, otherwise Bootstrap will override your css. (Or you can put !important beside everything -> not advised)

Anyways, rant over, the 3d effect you are seeing is a box shadow. Simply set the box shadow to none.

```css
button.btn.btn-default {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default active">INPUT</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```